# Windows DNS cache is NOT updating at all (other computers in home have updated)

Tags: windows-7, networking, firefox, dns

I just spun up a new VPS, set it up with a fresh and clean LAMP stack and pointed my domain to it.

I waited a few hours and tried it and it was still my old website. For a laugh, I logged into my shared FTP that it was pointing to before and added some text to the index file to see if it would update, **it did.**

I went to another computer in the house, in this case a laptop, and went to the domain. It was updated to the VPS (I got the "It works!" screen). I then tried my phone, it too had already updated.

At this point, I did the following:

- Cleared host file of Search and Destroy things (I had meant to do this earlier)
- Ran CCleaner and got rid of all Firefox internet cache
- Ran `ipconfig /flushdns` in console both under admin and regular user
- Deleted **all** browser cache via in-application tool in Firefox
- Refreshed page using `ctrl` + `f5`.
- Disabled and re-enabled network adapter via sharing center.
- Rebooted computer

I'm at a dead end. My computer has NEVER been this stubborn.

Can anyone help me out with getting it to update, seeing as other computers in the house already have?

**EDIT**
I pinged domain and received:

```
Pinging expunged [expunged] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from expunged: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=51
Reply from expunged: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=51
Reply from expunged: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=51
Reply from expunged: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for expunged:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 49ms, Maximum = 51ms, Average = 49ms
```

The IP it's saying it received is dead wrong. The IP should be: `expunged`

Comment: Are all devices using the same DNS server? sometimes DNS servers outside the LAN can take 72 hours to update.

Comment: **Problem Solved**

-----

As Ben Plont commented, the troublesome computer was on OpenDNS. I took it off and removed the static IP I had set up (for which I have no idea) and then disabled/enabled adapter and it works.

Thanks, Ben!

Comment: @Ramhound Just a question, I edited the answer. Is that how a good answer should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben Plont commented, the troublesome computer was on OpenDNS. I took it off and removed the static IP I had set up (for which I have no idea) and then disabled/enabled adapter and it works.

For anyone with the same problem, here is what I did with pictures:

(Windows 7)

Go to your start menu, and then to the control panel.

[image]

In the search area, type "network".

[image]

Click "Network and Sharing Center" and go to "Change Adapter Settings"

[image]

Right click the adapter you're using, for me, it's "Local Area Connection". Choose properties.

[image]

Left click the "IP Version 4" listing, and click "Properties".

[image]

Set both radio buttons to "Obtain automatically."

[image]

**Fin.**
Hope this helps.